# Host HTTP handler on fly

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, testing

I develop WCF service that has integration with some external system. Communication with external system in general sense is just sending GET requests and parsing response.

I what to emulate external system behavior in my Integration tests. So I'd like to create Mock HttpHandler and host it on local Work Station on some port (http://localhost:12312/externalprovider.ashx) then configure my WCF to work with this url and run some scenarios.

Is it possible to HOST HttpHandler on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. the httphandler is just an assembly. drop it in a folder, add a web.config & add a httphandler entry for example:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah/default.aspx" type="GotDotNet.Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, GotDotNet.Elmah, Version=1.0.5527.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=978d5e1bd64b33e5"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Comment: Integration Tests are in Class Library that is not hosted on IIS